# what is the way to send file from an amzon machine to a machine with ip range from 172 to 192

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, file-transfer

I have amazon machine i want to send file from that amazon machine to a machine under a private network.

I tried with ssh. it shows me error port: 22 connection time out.

How can i send file to particular machine in a private network with IP 172 to 192.

Comment: You don't. You "send the file" to a *public IP address* for the network, and then have the connection [*routed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) to the internal server/machine as appropriate. The 172/192 addresses you are referring to are [reserved for private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) and *cannot* be reached directly from Amazon. (An alternative may be to connect *to* Amazon - via a *public IP* - and fetch the file that way.)

Comment: I used public IP and try out in different port 80,8080,22,2222 but it shows port timeout to all the ports.    ssh -oPort=2222 sas@<publicIP> it show port :2222 timeout. I thing they blocked ssh trafic from any outside machine. If they do how  can i send file from amazon machine to that server.

Comment: check if your instance is running sshd daemon and if not start it.